# Jasper-iReport: Recursively print nested categories from XML datasource

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I am trying to print categories and (nested categories) sub categories defined in XML 
In following xml datasource **Mens Wear** subcategory as **Shirts** which further contain **T Shirts** and **Dress Shirts**. How can I recursively print these nested categories??

```
<categories>
    <category>
        <name>Mens Wear</name>
        <notes>Notes 1</notes>
        <categories>
            <category>
                <name>Jeans</name>
                <notes>Notes 2</notes>
            </category>
            <category>
                <name>Shirts</name>
                <notes>Notes 3</notes>
                <categories>
                    <category>
                        <name>T Shirts</name>
                        <notes>Notes 4</notes>
                    </category>
                    <category>
                        <name>Dress Shirts</name>
                        <notes>Notes 5</notes>
                    </category>
                </categories>
            </category>
        </categories>
    </category>
<categories>
```

In Jrxml the main XPATH query could be

```
/categories/category
```

name,notes,categories field

**Edit**
Haven't found a solution yet. but my work around was as follows.
I flattened the categories (removed the nesting),added an extra field for level (could be used for indentation or color change). And sort them in order as they need to to be displayed.

```
1 - Means Wear - 0
2 - Jeans - 1
3 - Red Jeans - 2
4 - Blue Jeans - 2
5 - Shirt - 1 (same level as of Jeans)
6 - Dress shirt - 2
7 - TShirt - 2
```

Comment: Did you find a solution how to show these fields repeatedly?

Comment: No my friend, Just added a work around to the original question. that might help you